# Trying to connect to prismic got " '[Link resolver error] Unknown type\n' "

Tags: javascript, prismic.io

So I'm running an app with nodejs + express, and trying to connect to the prismic API. keep getting " '[Link resolver error] Unknown type\n' ", I understand from the message it's something about my routes but I'm unsure how to fix it

**prismic config**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const prismic = require('@prismicio/client')

const repoName = process.env.PRISMIC_REPO_NAME
const accessToken = process.env.PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN
const endpoint = prismic.getEndpoint(repoName)

const routes = [
  {
    type: 'page',
    path: '/'
  }
]

module.exports.client = prismic.createClient(endpoint, {
  fetch,
  accessToken,
  routes
})
```

app.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const prismicH = require('@prismicio/helpers')
const { client } = require('./config/prismicConfig.js')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// template engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

// middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.ctx = {
    prismicH
  }
  next()
})

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const document = await client.getFirst()
  res.render('page', { document })
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/about')
})
app.get('/collections', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/collections')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

**prismic documents**
[image: prismic documents]

**folder structure**

[image: folder structure]

Edit: i fixed the issue
the issue was I was trying to render page, instead of pages/home

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const document = await client.getFirst()
  res.render('page', { document })
})
```

so i just edited the res.render to :

```
res.render('pages/home', { document })
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely being thrown because the routes object is not structured correctly. It should be structured like this:

```
const routes = {
  page: '/',
  blog_post: '/blog/:uid'
}

module.exports.client = prismic.createClient(endpoint, {
  fetch,
  accessToken,
  routes
})
```

Comment: unfortunately this not fixed the issue, it gets new error
type: 'Link resolver error',
message: `'type' is undefined on object: {"page":"/","blog_post":"/blog/:uid"}`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error,

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const document = await client.getFirst()
  res.render('page', { document })
})
```

the mistake was the I'm trying to render page, instead of pages/home so i edited this line

```
res.render('pages/home', { document })
```